# Does $\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\log(x)}dx$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Does $\displaystyle \int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{\log(x)}dx$ diverge? If so, how can we show it?

Answer (score 3):

Consider breaking up the integral into sub-interval integrals where the width of each sub-interval is $\pi$. Then the area under the curve for each sub-interval will alternate signs, and form an alternating series of area terms that converge to zero monotonically in absolute value because $\log x \to \infty$ monotonically. Can you see how to take it from there?